# Acceder al resultado de AXIOS JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo uso de la librería AXIOS de Javascript para llamadas al servidor y consumo de una API. Todo funciona bien, pero necesito saber como los elementos del resultado JSON se pueden meter en variables para acceder a ellos.

Por ejemplo, con HTTPRequest este código era el usado:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", $urlEnvio, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("accept" ,"application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type" ,"application/json");
xmlhttp.send($urlEnvio);

var resultado = xmlhttp.response;
var elementos =JSON.parse(resultado);
```

Esto me hacia la petición a la API y a continuación me insertaba los resultados en la variable elementos, pudiendo acceder a uno de ellos escribiendo elementos[0] o la posición que fuera.

Por otro lado, con AXIOS el fragmento funciona correctamente, pero la parte de JSON.parse usado con HTTPRequest no consigo aplicarla. Aquí el fragmento de mi solicitud con AXIOS:

```
axios.get(urlEnvio, usuario, clave)
.then(response => {
  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
  this.posts = response.data
  //var elementos = JSON.stringify(posts);
  alert(posts[0]);

})
```

En el alert me sale el mensaje UNDEFINED.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: hace console.log(response) y listo. posts no es lo mismo que this.posts, tené en cuenta que "this" cambia según el contexto, ahi this es parte de axios.get y no del objeto de afuera.

Comment: Hallé en algún lado que si se usa función flecha en lugar de función anónima se puede hacer uso de lo que se traiga de la instancia de Vue. Lo podrían confirmar, porque no soy experto en el tema pero estoy tratando de construir una API con Vue, Axios y node js y creo que este dato es un buen complemento para la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dice ahí, las respuestas en formato json son automaticamente parseadas (tenes que devolver json en la url de envio), entonces

```
var elementos = [];
axios.get(urlEnvio, usuario, clave)
.then(response => {
  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
  elementos = response.data;
});
```

PERO ten cuidado con lo que envias al get. Get acepta un segundo parámetro que son las request config, una de las opciones de config es param, así que deberías hacer

```
var elementos = [];
axios.get(urlEnvio, , {
 params: {
   user: usuario,
   pass: clave
 }
})
.then(response => {
  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
  elementos = response.data;
});
```

y un ejemplo de /login.php (por supuesto, nada seguro)

```
$response = [];
$response['logged'] = false;
if($_GET['user']=="oxxido" && $_GET['pass']=="superseguro") {
  $response['logged'] = true;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Mas info:**

aquí tenes ejemplos de get y save usando una api:

```
// GET request
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/oxxido')
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data); // ex.: { user: 'Your User'}
    console.log(response.status); // ex.: 200
  });  

// guardando POST request
axios.post('/save', { firstName: 'Oxxido', lastName: 'Test' })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('Guardado exitoso')
  });
```

Ten en cuenta dos cosas, "this" dentro de axios.get hace referencia al objeto axios, asi que usa con cuidado this. Axios.get devuelve una promesa, por lo que su ejecución es asincrónica.

saludos!